# How to drop multiple triggers in a PostgreSQL 9.1 DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to remove multiple triggers but getting a SQL error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1:     DROP TRIGGER rr_admin_reports;
```

Here is the sql I'm executing in rails:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  DROP TRIGGER rr_admin_reports;
  DROP TRIGGER rr_apps;
  DROP TRIGGER rr_attachments;
SQL
```

Is there a way to easily delete a long list of triggers? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
DROP TRIGGER rr_admin_reports ON yourTable;
```

Quote from PostgreSQL documentation:

> *The DROP TRIGGER statement in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard. In the SQL standard, trigger names are not local to tables, so the command is simply DROP TRIGGER name.*

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-droptrigger.html

Comment: Is there a way to say DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS?

Comment: Yes use: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS rr_admin_reports ON yourTable; :)